# SingularException(2) when invoking multivariate Newton's method in Julia

Tags: julia, newtons-method

I have implemented the multivariate Newton's method in Julia.

```
function newton(f::Function, J::Function, x)
   h = Inf64
   tolerance = 10^(-10)
   while (norm(h) > tolerance)
      h = J(x)\f(x)
      x = x - h
   end
   return x
end
```

On the one hand, when I try to solve the below system of equations, `LoadError: SingularException(2)` is thrown.

```
f(θ) = [cos(θ[1]) + cos(θ[2] - 1.3),
        sin(θ[1]) + sin(θ[2]) - 1.3]
J(θ) = [-sin(θ[1]) -sin(θ[2]); 
        cos(θ[1]) cos(θ[2])]
θ = [pi/3, pi/7]
newton(f, J, θ)
```

On the other hand, when I try to solve this other system

```
f(x) = [(93-x[1])^2 + (63-x[2])^2 - 55.1^2, 
        (6-x[1])^2 + (16-x[2])^2 - 46.2^2]
J(x) = [-2*(93-x[1]) -2*(63-x[2]); -2*(6-x[1]) -2*(16-x[2])]
x = [35, 50]
newton(f, J, x)
```

no errors are thrown and the correct solution is returned.

Furthermore, if I first solve the second system and then try to solve the first system, which normally throwns `SingularException(2)`, I now instead encounter no errors but am returned a totally inaccurate solution to the first system.

What exactly is going wrong when I try to solve the first system and how can I resolve the error?

Comment: I do not get an error with `θ` values you provided. The solution returned is `2.8362753819900477, 1.6053172714191895`. Feeding the solution back to `f`, I get something near `0`. However, if you enter any `θ` so that `sin(θ[2]-θ[1])=0`, e.g. `[pi/3, pi/3]`, then you will get a singular `J` hence the error.

Comment: Also, try not to enter integer input like `[35, 50]`, it will cause type-instability since `x` will be put in a subtraction with `h`, a `Float64` array. Instead, you can use `[35., 50.]`. You also have a type instability issue with `h`. it is first a scalar, then an array.

Comment: @hckr Seems like restarting Julia solved the problem. Now I too get the same values as you.